# How do I use variable names using a for loop to reference a number in the variable name?

Tags: php, sql, variables, concatenation, operator-keyword

```
$_SESSION_Job101=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT progress FROM job_101 WHERE username='$_SESSION_User'"));
$_SESSION_Job102=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT progress FROM job_102 WHERE username='$_SESSION_User'"));
$_SESSION_Job103=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT progress FROM job_103 WHERE username='$_SESSION_User'"));
$_SESSION_Job104=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT progress FROM job_104 WHERE username='$_SESSION_User'"));
$_SESSION_Job105=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT progress FROM job_105 WHERE username='$_SESSION_User'"));
$_SESSION_Job106=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT progress FROM job_106 WHERE username='$_SESSION_User'"));
$_SESSION_Job107=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT progress FROM job_107 WHERE username='$_SESSION_User'"));
$_SESSION_Job108=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT progress FROM job_108 WHERE username='$_SESSION_User'")); 
$_SESSION_Job109=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT progress FROM job_109 WHERE username='$_SESSION_User'"));
$_SESSION_Job1010=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT progress FROM job_110 WHERE username='$_SESSION_User'"));

for ($x=1;$x<=10;$x++)
{
$e = '$_SESSION_Job10'.$x;
//if ($e >= 100)
//{ $_SESSION_Job10.$x.['progress'] = 100; }
echo $e;
}
```

I can get the $e variable to return the variable I want, however I want $e to essentially act as that variable in my if statement, not just return its name. When I remove the comment from the if statement, my page goes blank instead of echoing $e. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
$e = ${'_SESSION_Job10'.$x}; // $e = $_SESSION_Job101; actual variable here
```

### *Live Demo*

instead of

```
$e = '$_SESSION_Job10'.$x;   // $e = '$_SESSION_Job101'; // string here
```

**Edit**

You have to use array like this

```
${'_SESSION_Job10'.$x}['progress'];
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/QoopeS38)

Comment: I receive the following error when I swapped that code out:

Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION_Job10 in /home4/dbkgames/public_html/scripts/update.php on line 33
12345678910

Comment: Okay, the issue is apparently with my variable that I'm inserting into $e. It returns the value of "Array".

In the same vein that you did, am I able to add a third value inside the {} operator? Such as: ${'_SESSION_Job10'.$x."['progress']"};

Comment: @MikiferBlair in your code `$x` is not array. And this code is your real code?

Comment: @MikiferBlair And yes `$_SESSION_Job101` is array. So `$e` will be array, you have to iterate this array for retrieving its value.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear. The variables $_SESSION_Job101, 102, etc. are returning the value of "Array" when I echo them. 

Yes, this is my real code. The $_SESSION_Job101 variables do work, as I frequently reference them in other scripts. They store an entire row of data from the table that is referenced in their query's.

Comment: @MikiferBlair So as I said iterate them using while loop or for loop.

Comment: Okay I see where I was messing up in my head. So using the line of code you previously gave me, is there a way I can assign $e to be the value of $_SESSION_Job101['progress'] ?

I tried $e = ${'_SESSION_Job10'.$x.'['progress']'}; but no luck

Comment: That worked perfectly. I was unaware of the correct syntax to use there. Thank you very much!

Comment: Can I assume that I can also assign variables the same way? I.E. ${'_SESSION_Job10'.$x}['progress'] = $e;